# When will Pagedown be moved to Github?

Tags: discussion, markdown

According to [StackExchange's Github page](http://stackexchange.github.io/), PageDown is still a Mercurial repo [hosted on Google Code](https://code.google.com/p/pagedown/). However Google Code is going to become read-only on August 25, 2015 and it'd be nice for PageDown to be moved to live with the other repos in the [StackExchange organization on Github](https://github.com/StackExchange)

Is this going to happen? If so when?

Comment: It's worth mentioning that there are many people who have already made copies of the PageDown repo in github. Such as https://github.com/ujifgc/pagedown. But none of them seem to be official (I'd expect it to be on the StackExchange org w/ the other repos they have).

Comment: Bitbucket is more Mecurial

Comment: Bitbucket certainly is mercurial, but StackExchange already has a [presence on Github](https://github.com/StackExchange) and Google Code has a nice "Export to Github" button.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This same question appears in the discussion under this initial question on Meta StackOverflow:
[What's the Markdown Editor that Stack Overflow is using?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/305584/5455641)

The answer there states they will migrate to Github when they have pagedown changes to commit and the official [StackExchange Github page](http://stackexchange.github.io/) says that the PageDown repo is https://github.com/balpha/pagedown

Comment: It seems the [stack exchange github page](http://stackexchange.github.io/) has changed and pagedown is now on github here: [balpha/pagedown](https://github.com/balpha/pagedown)

Comment: Question remains: [is this the official pagedown copy?](https://github.com/balpha/pagedown/issues/87)

Comment: A StackExchange employee changed the stackexchange.github.io page in this commit: https://github.com/StackExchange/stackexchange.github.com/commit/18adc3f42ce19825967a01f138fe7b5ae926882e

So I'd say it probably is the official repo now.