# Using hyperlink shortcut Ctrl+l causes loss of up/down arrow keys

Tags: bug, editor

After using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>l</kbd> to link highlighted text when writing and answer or question, I can no longer use my up/down keys unless I leave the page and come back to it.

I am having an issue in FireFox 47.0.1, although I have noticed this in all previous versions as well. Windows 7 x64 if that matters.

I disabled all of my add-ons and verified this issue before posting this report.

Comment: I can see the same on FF 47.0.1, Windows 10. Not sure if this is a bug on the FF side or the SE side.

Comment: I'm guessing that this is the same issue as this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/264307/down-arrow-key-wont-work-after-using-the-hyperlink-button

Comment: Can't reproduce on FF 47.0, OS X. so looks like a Windows issue.